# How to attemp sec:loggedInUserInfo into a variable in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to get value of sec:loggedInUserInfo and attempt into a variable named user.

My code looks like this:

```
<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" /> 

<%
  def user = *value of field loggedInUserInfo *
%>
```

Is it possible for doing that?

Answer (score 11):

This is simpler and works fine for me:

```
<g:set var="user" value="${sec.username()}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

To assign any field of the UserDetails instance referred to by [<sec:loggedInUserInfo>](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib) to a variable you can use:

```
<g:set var="fullName" value="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:'fullName')}" />
```

(see also [Custom User Details](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService))

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user object in the gsp, just pass it back as part of the model map from the controller.  in a controller action do

```
def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
render view: 'yourgsp', model: [user: user]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we can use that tag directly, I couldn't find it earlier, so I have made my custom tag for this purpose

`<m:userName id="${session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.authentication?.principal?.id}"/>`

```
def userName = { attrs ->
Long id = attrs['id'] ? attrs['id'].toLong() : null
User user = User?.get(id);
out << user?.firstName
```

}

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one taglib as loggedinUser which is added on gsp page as :

```
Welcome <g:loggedInUser/> !
```

Which is showing logged In username on top of each gsp in my project. In custom tag library my code is as follows :

```
def springSecurityService

def loggedInUser={
    if(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().equals("anonymousUser")){
        response.sendRedirect("${request.contextPath}/login/auth")
    }else{
        out <<"${springSecurityService.currentUser.username}"
        out << """ [${link(controller:"logout"){"Logout"}}]"""
    }
}
```

So it's showing on each page as : Welcome USERNAME[Logout] !